# Centering elements on the browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, fullpage.js

I'm making my first web template but I have some problems. I'm using the [FullPage.js script](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and I want to center the content I add with this script, both vertically and horizontally. Here is the website I'm doing (fullpagewebsite.blogspot.com).

As you can notice, if you scroll down with your keyboard new content will appear. But this content is shown in that weird and ugly position (left top corner).

I want this content to be on the center of the page.

```
<table id="Table_01" width="900" height="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="BrowserPreview_tmp_01.png?1424981576" width="900" height="225" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="BrowserPreview_tmp_02.png?1424981576" width="84" height="175" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="BrowserPreview_tmp_03.png?1424981576" width="350" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="BrowserPreview_tmp_04.png?1424981576" width="52" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="BrowserPreview_tmp_05.png?1424981576" width="344" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="BrowserPreview_tmp_06.png?1424981576" width="70" height="122" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="BrowserPreview_tmp_07.png?1424981576" width="816" height="53" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Yes, I know I'm using tables and I know that's not a good idea. But I NEED to work With Photoshop and the codes that Photoshop give me. And these codes are tables.

How can I do to center that?

Comment: You are using PhotoShop as a web authoring tool? PhotoShop generates your HTML?

Comment: The fact that you disabled my scrollbar makes me want to stab something.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, you can cut the image and then photoshop gives you the code for websites

Comment: @isherwood Haha sorry, I'll try to fix that

Comment: You're going to be nothing but disappointed if you continue down the path you're going. Table layouts were out of fashion almost a decade ago, and for good reason. Either upgrade Photoshop so it gives you modern markup, or do some reading about HTML and CSS. It's not terribly difficult to achieve this kind of layout these days using the many great example sites as guides.

Answer (score 0):

To center your table horizontally all you need to do is give your table the css properties/values of "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"

So for example:

```
<table id="Table_01" width="900" height="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; ">
```

As far as centering it vertically, that gets trickier. You can either do it with a pre-defined static margin, ie: "margin-top: 20px;", or you can use Javascript to get the height of your table, and then decide how much to push it down.

An example of some JS that could work is as follows:

```
<script>
$('#fullpage table').each(function() {
  $(this).css('margin-top', function(){
    return ($(this).parent().height() - $(this).height()) / 2;
  });
});
</script>
```

And it would go at the bottom of your page.

edit,
there are also now options in the form of CSS to do vertical centering but it can get tedious depending on the scope. See Flexbox for more information on this route.